# AttributeError: type object 'Auth' has no attribute 'query'

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

So I've been using this method for a few projects now but for some reason I'm getting an error.

Code involved:

```
class Auth(db.Column):
    __tablename__ = 'ezauth'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Auth(username='{self.username}', email='{self.email}', password='{self.password}'"
```

and

```
@app.route('/api/login', methods=['POST'])
def apilogin():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        if email != None and password != None:
            value1 = Auth.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
            if value1 != None:
                db_pass = value1.password
                oid = value1.id
                if sha256_crypt.verify(str(password), db_pass):
                    token = create_token()
                    tokendb = Token(token=token, oid=oid)
                    return Response('{"success": true, "message": "Logged in", "token": "' + str(token) + '"}', status=200, mimetype='application/json')
                else:
                    return Response('{"success": false, "message": "Incorrect password"}', status=400, mimetype='application/json')
            else:
                return Response('{"success": false, "message": "Email not registered"}', status=400, mimetype='application/json')
        else:
            return Response('{"success": false, "message": "Wrong form parameters"}', status=400, mimetype='application/json')
```

But, the `Auth.query.all()` (or any other variation on `Auth.query`) doesn't work for some reason, it returns the `AttributeError: type object 'Auth' has no attribute 'query'` error. It has worked in previous projects, just not this one.

Comment: There is no `Auth.query.all()` in the code you provided. You also did this in your code, `Auth.query.filter_by(email=email).first()`, does it    raise an error.

Comment: @Nerveless_child I used `Auth.query.all()` as an example, it's about the "query" attribute not anything else (like `filter_by()` or `first()` instead of `all()`).

Comment: Are you sure `Auth` is meant to subclass `db.Column` instead of `db.Model`?

Comment: I believe that's the cause of your error.

Comment: @Nerveless_child damn, guess I'm just dumb. Thanks for noticing!